# How to read depot's folders structure by p4python without syncing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, perforce, p4python

I'd like to read folders and files structure inside a specified folder path on the P4 depot without syncing it. Is it possible?

Comment: `p4 files <depot path>...` will provide required information on CLI. Is it not possible to run this command using `p4.run()`?

Comment: And to determine folder structure, use `p4 dirs` in a similar fashion.

Comment: @SilentMonk @BryanPendleton thanks guys, `p4.run("dirs", path+'*')` and `p4.run("files", path+'*')` do exactly what i needed

Comment: @smoke_lp, you are welcome. I think you should answer your question in the answer section combining both the comments. Other users would find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get subfolders of specified depot path one should use this code

```
p4.run("dirs", path+'*')
```

The result will be a list of single-item dictionaries

```
[{'dir': '//Depot/path/dirname1'}, {'dir': '//Depot/path/dirname2'}]
```

In order to get all files contained within specified depot path one should use:

```
p4.run("files", path+'*')
```

The result will be a list of dictionaries one for each file:

```
[{'rev': '1', 'time': '1465999632', 'action': 'add', 'type': 'text', 'depotFile': '//Depot/path/dirname1/filename.txt', 'change': '999999'}]
```

Also please note that specified path must end with a slash /

Thanks to @SilentMonk @BryanPendleton for giving me hints

Answer (score 0):

Note that running using Dirs and Files to recursively iterate through a directory tree is inefficient if you're planning to populate the entire tree.

If you need file info for all files under a directory, including its children, it's orders of magnitudes faster to just issue the "files" command to include the entire tree (i.e. path/... as opposed to path/*).

I suspect this is because the P4 server has no concept of directories, internally.  A file's "directory" in P4 is just the last path-separated token in the file's path.  So, it has to do extra work to slice its file set into a directory-specific list.